# Oracle + NiFi => all fields converted to String

Tags: apache, oracle11g, avro, apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi to transfer Oracle (11g) database tables to HDFS (Avro format).

Something goes wrong with the typing of the AVRO columns: they are all defined as String, even when the Oracle tablecolumn is of another type like Numeric, Timestamp of Datetime. Clearly, this is annoying :-)

After some googling, I found suggestions that the problem exists in the combination of certain Oracle JDBC drivers and the converter to Avro. However, I could not find a proper solution; does anyone know what JDBC (or other?) driver to use in order to have correct typing in the Avro output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation for the unexpected behaviour:

1. Oracle uses NUMBER even if the column is defined with INT [1] (This
   is not a driver side issue, I guess.)
2. 2JDBC driver maps Number to BigDecimal
3. NiFi implementation maps BigDecimal to String, since at that time,
   Avro didn't support BigDecimal mapping until Avro 1.8.1. Current
   NiFi uses Avro 1.7.7. With Avro 1.8.1, we can utilize LogicalType
   [2] to map BigDecimal or Date more user friendly way.
4. There's an ongoing effort in NiFi project [3] to use LogicalType
   mechanism, so that those data types can be mapped with more
   appropriate data types.

In other words, it seems I'll have to wait for a next release where this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If the driver is returning "string" as the type for each column as Bryan suggested (or an unknown type that NiFi treats as a string), then if you know the expected column types, for primitive type conversions (string, long, int, double, float) you could try the [ConvertAvroSchema](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.kite.ConvertAvroSchema/index.html) processor.

For date/time fields, depending on what you'd like to do with them, there are some [Date Manipulation functions](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#dates) in NiFi Expression Language that could help you process them.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, what you suggest is a (non-sustainable) workaround.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting a workaround until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2624 is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with using Oracle to say which driver works, but in order for it work correctly in NiFi the driver has to support using the ResultSetMetaData to get the column type:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/ba513447d75dc5e95ddcdfcac1a1fefe2eb175ce/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/util/JdbcCommon.java#L100-L108

It sounds like the driver you are using is returning string for every column.